# Best way around displaying multiple images from URLs in an NSString

Tags: ios, objective-c, nsstring

I'm currently working on an application that downloads posts from a Wordpress blog and displays them for a user to view. The current obstacle I've run into is that the blog uses a large number of images within their posts, and the wording of text is quite dependent on having those images in the right place (so they can't be at the bottom of the view, for example).

The solution I've come up with so far would be to use one of the `NSString` methods to look through the text and find all the sections containing **img** and then grab those out and separate the `NSString` at that point. Then I would use a bunch of if statements to work out how many sections there were, and lay out the `UIScrollView` from there.

To me this sounds like a horrible solution, so I'm hoping there is a better one out there someone could recommend.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

OK. First take a look at [DTCoreText Framework](https://github.com/Cocoanetics/DTCoreText) (parse HTML tagged text and can handle 'img'-tags).

The second: Easly all images have the same size (e.g. images must groped or so). Count the img-tags and you now the needed space.

A good way is to load the images asynchronous....